# Adding CSRF to custom Zend Forms

Tags: php, zend-framework, request, csrf

I have built a series of custom forms that don't use the ZEND form class. I would like to add CSRF protection using the ZEND classes, but all the examples I look at use the form class.

How would I go about implementing CSRF protection to my manually created forms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474774/how-to-use-zend-framework-form-hash-token-with-ajax

Comment: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.element.csrf.html